# Google indexing https for homepage, breaking layout - solutions? (magento)

Tags: magento, ssl, https, indexing, magento-1.6

It seems google has started indexing the secure url for my magento site's homepage - this has caused the CSS and JS links to break a la https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/896/https-layout-broken, but I'm not sure how to fix it, as the answer in that thread didn't explain what needed to be changed, and I wouldn't even know where to start with google

Does anyone know of a solution to either stop google indexing the secure homepage, or what to do to allow the CSS and JS files to have secure urls?

Comment: Tried to use the https url as unsecure baseurl, too?

Comment: Hey Simon, That was a solution I looked into, but unfortunately it causes a few issues with other things - I think from reading up on it that magento provides the css and js links as unsecure unless you specify otherwise in the layout files, but I'm unsure as to how to specify that they can be provided securely